# Android - fade in new activity from Recyclerview: unresolved reference overridePendingTransition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

This is the code inside recyclerview Adapter:

```
val i = Intent(context, DownloadImage::class.java)
i.putExtras(extras)
context.startActivity(i)
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
```

I get unresolved reference on `overridePendingTransition`

I know it's because overridePendingTransition isn't in `RecyclerView.Adapter` but how to do it then?

`context.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)` isn't working too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do that :

```
  ((Activity)context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Comment: I get "Classifier 'Activity' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here" on Activity

Comment: No, just try it

Comment: This worked: "(context as Activity).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)" I'll still accept because you gave me an idea :D Maybe your solution only works in JAVA and not Kotlin